# How to INSERT multiple Values using Parameters WITHOUT declaring a SQL Server Type?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

Like the title says, I'm trying to insert multiple values into SQL Server using an `INSERT` command dynamically constructed in code.

The command looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO xLog (value1, value2, value3) 
VALUES (@xLog);
```

And, following multiple other answers in this site, the parameter `@xLog` is an array of `SqlDataRecord` that contains the collection of values to insert (I have also followed the `DataTable` approach that was also suggested, with the same result as below).

But, when I try to execute this command, I get this error:

> The table type parameter '@xLog' must have a valid type name.

...which I understand occurs because SQL Server is expecting a custom type to be created in the database that follows the parameter's structure. Let's say that I would prefer NOT to have create this custom type for X reason.

So the question is: is there a way to insert multiple rows into SQL Server, with parameters, from .net code, without using custom types OR stored procedures?

Thank you for your time.

Note to mods: I tagged with both vb.net and c# tags because I can use code in both languages. Thanks.

Comment: What's the endgame here?  Are you simply trying to avoid specifying the data types for the values you're providing?  Why exactly is that?

Comment: Well yeah, I'm trying to avoid having to alter existing databases as it will not always be possible. If I can make an insert without having to create a custom SQL Type, I won't have to alter any table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2)  (possibly in combination with a temp table), or pass a JSON or XML document and shred it in TSQL.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy it is. Thank you.